# Polling multiple SQS messages using Airflow SQSSensor

Tags: airflow, amazon-sqs, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am using this SQSSensoe settings to poll messages

```
    fetch_sqs_message = SQSSensor(
        task_id="...",
        sqs_queue="...",
        aws_conn_id="aws_default",
        max_messages=10,
        wait_time_seconds=30,
        poke_interval=60,
        timeout=300,
        dag=dag
    )
```

I would assume everytime it polls it should poll up to 10 messages. Which my queue has around 5 when I tested this.
But each time I trigger the dag, it only polls 1 message at a time, which I found out from the SQS message count.
Why is it doing this? How can I to get it poll as much messages as possible?

Comment: Valid values for `wait_time_in_seconds` should be between 0-20 seconds. Also, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104343/5189811) for how long polling works in SQS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, a new feature has been added to `SQSSensor` so that the sensor can polls SQS multiple times instead of only once.

You can check out [this merged PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24554#event-6893695430)

For example, if `num_batches` is set to 3, `SQSSensor` will poll the queue 3 times before returning the results.

Disclaimer: I contributed to this feature.